# How to replace words larger than 30 characters from a string via vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to extract words that have no meaning from a paragraph or have some special characters - they could be random links to a

I tried using regex but couldn't achieve successful results .

Input sample

```
 The quick brown fox ran over the lazy dog https//kidsnursuery.com/ghyds/
```

Output sample

```
The quick brown fox ran over the lazy dog
```

Comment: Can you share your regex attempt? This will give us some insight as to what your criteria may be. Is there any consistent rule that can be applied at all? In your given example, you could easily split the string by spaces and see if each value in array has any non-alpha characters. One example isn't really enough to extrapolate to a full blown solution though...

Comment: regex https://regex101.com/r/zJMqBA/2

Comment: For the sample data you get the right string with `=LEFT(A1,(SEARCH("HTTP??",A1,1)-1))` where `A1` contains your string.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said in comments, the task of identifying "words that have no meaning" really requires you to define what "no meaning" actually means for your context.

Taking your question literally, you might want to look at the `CheckSpelling()` function, which returns `False` if a word doesn't exist in the current or specified dictionary. You'd call the function as below:

```
Dim items() As String
Dim i As Long

items = Split("The quick brown fox ran over the lazy dog https//kidsnursuery.com/ghyds/", " ")

For i = 0 To UBound(items)
    If Not Application.CheckSpelling(items(i)) Then
        items(i) = vbNullString
    End If
Next

Debug.Print Join(items, " ")
```